# Calculator With Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, calculator

I am having a bit of a problem how to pass an array in a method to another method that will use the user defined inputs to add,subtract,multiply etc.

When I enter in the amount of variables per array, I do not get the results I am expecting.

IE:

How many values in array?: 2

How many variables in array 1?: 1, 2

How many variables in array 2?: 1, 2

The answers I should expect is 2, 4

Is there an issue I am having?

Thanks,

Ryan

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choice = 0;
    int i = 3;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    getMenuOption(choice, i, num1, num2);
}

public static int getMenuOption(int choice, int i, int num1, int num2) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean cont = true;
    while (cont = true) {
        System.out.println("Menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Add two numbers ");
        System.out.println("2. Subtract two numbers ");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply tow Numbers ");
        System.out.println("4. Divide two numbers ");
        System.out.println("5. Generate a Random Number");
        System.out.println("6. Exit the Program");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("What is your choice? : ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            add(num1, num2);
        } // end of if statement
        if (choice == 2) {
            subtract(num1, num2);
        } // end of if statement
        if (choice == 3) {
            multiply(num1, num2);
        } // end of if statement
        if (choice == 4) {
            divide(num1, num2);
        } // end of if statement
        if (choice == 5) {
            random(num1, num2);
        } // end of if statement
        if (choice == 6) {
            System.exit(0);
        } // end of if statement
        if (choice <= 0 || choice >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect choice please try again!");
            i--;
            int tries = i;
            System.out.println(tries + " tries left before restart");
            if (tries <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you must restart this program.");
                System.exit(0);
            } // end of of tries statement

        } // end of if choice statement
        if (choice == 1 || choice <= 6) {
            i = 3;
        } // end of if choice statement
    }
    return 0;
}

public static double getOperand(String prompt) { // Used for giving inputs
                                                    // and returns value to
                                                    // method/
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(prompt);

    int value = input.nextInt();

    return value;
}

public static int getOperand1(String prompt, int size) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many values in array?");
    size = input.nextInt();
    int arraySize[] = new int[size];
    System.out.println("You have made " + size + " values with arrays.");
    return size;
}

public static double add(double operand1, double operand2) { // adds the two
                                                                // inputs
                                                                // given to
                                                                // program
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double answer = 0;
    operand1 = getOperand("Please enter the first number: ");
    operand2 = getOperand("Please enter second number: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <; i++){
    answer = operand1 + operand2;
    }
    System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);

    return 0;
}

public static double[] subtract(double operand1, double operand2) { // subtracts
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // two
                                                                    // inputs
                                                                    // given
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // program
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = 0;
    operand1 = getOperand("Please enter the first number: ");
    operand2 = getOperand("Please enter the second number: ");
    answer = (int) (operand1 - operand2);
    System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
    return null;
}

public static double[] multiply(double operand1, double operand2) { // multiplys
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // two
                                                                    // inputs
                                                                    // given
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // program
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = 0;
    operand1 = getOperand("Please enter the first number: ");
    operand2 = getOperand("Please enter the second number: ");
    answer = (int) (operand1 * operand2);
    System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
    return null;
}

public static double divide(double operand1, double operand2) { // Gets a
                                                                // dividend
                                                                // from two
                                                                // sets of
                                                                // numbers
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = 0;
    operand1 = getOperand("Please enter the first number: ");
    operand2 = getOperand("Please enter the second number: ");
    answer = (int) (operand1 / operand2);
    if (operand2 <= 0) {
        return (Double) null;
    } else
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
    return Double.NaN;
}

public static double[] random(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit) { // Gets
                                                                        // a
                                                                        // random
                                                                        // Num
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double upperLimit1 = getOperand("Please enter the Maximum Number : ");
    double lowerLimit1 = getOperand("Please enter the Minimum Number : ");
    Random rand = new Random();
    double ranNum = rand.nextInt() + lowerLimit1;
    System.out.println("Your random number is: " + ranNum);
    return null;
}
```

}
I am needing the program to do something like this:[Program Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3D9b.png)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <; i++){` - This line in the `add` method looks wrong.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.  If you want to pass an array into a method, you can do that.  Instead of `public static double add(double operand1, double operand2) {` you can do `public static double add(double[] operand1, double[] operand2) {` and now the method will take arrays of doubles (instead of doubles) as parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see quite some issues with your code. First, though, your intention isn’t clear. Seems you should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once more.

Comment: Lemme guess, when you ask “How many variables in array 1?”, did you really mean *what* are the values in array 1?? If the user chose addition, is your program supposed to add the first element of array 1 to the first element of array 2 and so forth until the end of the arrays?

Comment: That is very correct. I am trying to create multiple arrays that would store values and then add,subtract etc to array 1 and array 2.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an issue you are having? I see quite some.

- Your loop only stops through `System.exit()`. You may as well use just `while (true)`. `while (cont = true)` is in fact a tricky error: it *assigns* `true` to `cont`, then tests whether is `true`. Guess the result. Use `==` for comparison (as in `if (choice == 1)`), or even better, use just `while (cont)` if you want your loop to run as long as `cont` is `true`.
- It’s `getOperand1()` that asks `How many values in array?`, but you never call this method.
- To allow the user to enter more values on a line separated by commas, you need a way to read the entire line and a way to take out the individual values. I would use `Scanner.nextLine()`, `String.split()`, `String.trim()` and either `Integer.parseInt()` or `Double.parseDouble()`.
- Your divide method will crash if the user enters a second operand that is 0 or less than 0. The method is declared to return `double`, but in the mentioned case you return `null`, which Java will try to convert to a double, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

Less important:

- You are creating a wealth of `Scanner` objects. Better create just one and use it throughout the program.
- Your random number generation does not respect the limits entered. I entered `100` and `10` and got `-1.188932703E9`, that is, -1188932703 (nice feature, though, that I can have a random number).
- It seems you haven’t made a final decision about when to use `int` and when to use `double`. For example, you are passing two `int` arguments to `add()`, but the method is declared to have two `double` parameters.

Please take no offence, if that was me, I’d prefer to practice with some smaller programs first, get some more experience before embarking on one this size. Feel free to discard the thought if it doesn’t suit you.

D M demonstrated in a comment how to pass an array to a method. You may also return an array from a method, for example:

```
public double[] getArrayOfOperands(int arraySize) {
    double[] operands = new double[arraySize];
    // fill array somehow
    return operands;
}
```

Edit: A design suggestion (again, feel free to discard): The methods for the arithmetic operations (add, subtract, etc.) should not take numbers as arguments, instead they should take a `Scanner` object that they use for reading input from the user/keyboard. Each such method would first call a method `getArraySize` where the user is prompted for how many values should be in each array (this is returned as an `int`). Next the method would twice call a method `getArrayOfOperands` to prompt the user for values. This method should take three arguments: the `Scanner`, a prompt and the desired array size. And should return an array. After these three calls, you’re ready for doing the calculation.

Comment: That is very helpful! I agree that I should start off with a smaller program, but it seems the assignments I have build off of this program. I think I should just create another java program and get the necessary features first.

Comment: That method is very useful for me. I have looked at how to do arrays within methods and pass the arrays to methods but your explanation is a lot more clear for me! Is this looking a bit better? `public static double[] getArraySize(int arraySize){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many arrays?: ");
  arraySize = input.nextInt();
  double[] operands = new double[arraySize];
  
  return operands;`

Comment: Yeah, you’re on the way! :-)